# Is it the Rails Way to build a single giant application, or modularize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We are in the processing of building a new version of our application from the ground up. Our current Rails application, which has been in production for 5 years and has 100 models. I am considering ways to simplify the codebase for the next version.

I can see Reporting Features and Admin Features being broken out. Most everything in the application in Product-based though. Even breaking out the Reporting, I would have to duplicate models, which is obviously not suboptimal.

I am aware of Rails Engines, I am just not certain if that feature is as robust as it should be. Another concern is designing this application based on Rails 3.2 when Rails 4 is already in beta.

I'm not looking for this to be an opinion piece, I was just curious to see if there was a convention for breaking out modules vs. building an all-encompassing application. The convention either exists in the community or it doesn't. Thanks for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: I think gems like spree or refinery are good examples of app splitting

Comment: Engines seem to be very robust, and a number of gems use them.  It's absolutely the case that splitting out components into separate libraries is a good practice -- I don't think anyone likes the idea of a huge, monolithic app.  Another way of thinking about this may be to decide if you really have several different "services" or if your data could be partitioned in some way.  Indeed, you could run these services as separate Rails apps if that made sense.  It really depends on what your app does, but you're thinking exactly the right thoughts!

Comment: On the point about waiting for Rails 4, from what I can see there aren't a huge number of gut-wrenching changes (as there were from 2 to 3, for example).  A lot of the cool functionality is available as 3.2-compatible gems now.  So maybe write in 3.2, and build for 4.0  using the beta on a branch as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is generally:

- Build as one application
- Have the classes know as little as possible about other classes
- Extract when it hurts

Extracting to either engines or to services (service-oriented-architecture) is a decision for your scalability requirements.

Comment: Good answer!  My assumption was that it hurts already (100 models seems like enough to justify extraction now).  But I might add one other suggestion to your list before the extraction, especially when doing a big rewrite, which is to find code, data and modules that could be eliminated, or refactored.  After 5 years, apps get baggage.  If it was reasonably well designed from the start, it can be a good first step just to have a good, old-fashioned "code burning" :-)

Comment: I think we had 125 models before the last public burning ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*I would have to duplicate models...*

You might consider moving the models into a gem, and including the gem in each application.